# Is saying "an obsolete remnant" redundant?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, redundancy

Is saying "**an obsolete remnant**" or "**an old remnant**" redundant (or tautologous), or can the adjective be necessary to convey what I'm trying to say?

(I imagined "remnant" already carries the connotation of "obsolete" to some extent, but looking at [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/remnant), maybe that is not the case.)

**Bonus question**: Is there a better noun for "something that's remaining or left behind, yet obsolete"?

Comment: You can have carpet remnants, and carpet is not obsolete.

Comment: Context whence the question arose: in a software project, a file that had been laying in version control for a year, originally added with some intention in mind, but actually serving no purpose whatsoever. What to call that file?

Comment: I would call it a 'relic'("An old, outmoded, or outdated person or thing"), if it were simply too old to use, or maybe a 'white elephant' if it were a project that never really got going ~ "an object, scheme, etc., considered to be without use or value."

Comment: @RoaringFish: Yeah, "relic" is good. What lead me to think of "remnant" was the Finnish word *jäänne*, which actually better translates to "relic" or "remains" now that I looked it up.

Comment: @Jonik RE your comment specifically: I'd call that file an "obsolete file".

Comment: The problem with relic is that it can also have the meaning of "old and valuable artifact", which is precisely the opposite meaning to that which is required here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we take *remnant* to mean *a small part of something that is left over*, *obsolete* and *old* need not be redundant. Even if *obsolete* and *old* are taken to be part of the connotations of the word, they would serve as intensifiers of the meaning.

Answer (score 11):

First, let's get the basics clear.

> **Obsolete:** no longer used; out of date
>
> **Remnant:** a part or quantity that is left after the greater part has been used, removed, or destroyed
>
> **Old:** old

So, "obsolete" and "old" are not redundant in the phrases you have provided.

As for the *bonus question*, you could try:

- Vestige
- Remainder
- Leftover
- Remains

(The choice of the synonym - for the bonus question -  would depend entirely upon the context of the statement where it is to be used.)

Comment: Thanks! (I sdded some context as a comment to the question.)

Comment: @Jonik You could call such a file to be *redundant* or *superfluous*.

Comment: A "remnant" is not necessarily "old" at all. If, say, you are installing carpet and have a remnant, at the instant it becomes a remnant it is exactly as new as the carpet that was installed. Also, carpet stores routinely sell such remnants at a discount to be used as small rugs and the like, so a remnant is not necessarily useless or obsolete.

Comment: @Jay Where have I written that a "remnant" is necessarily old?

Comment: @rudra You didn't. I was agreeing with you. (Don't be so defensive. :-)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in a previous answer, *[remnant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/remnant)* (a remaining portion) does not denote *[old](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/old)* or *[obsolete](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/obsolete)* (old, disused).

Regarding part 2 of the question, the previously-suggested terms *[vestige](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vestige?rdfrom=Vestige)*, *[remainder](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/remainder)*, *[redundant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/redundant)*, and *[superfluous](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/superfluous)* are all very well, but the "proper term" for obsolete bits of software left lying about in a project is *[cruft](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cruft)*, "Redundant, old or improperly written code, especially that which accumulates over time; clutter".

Comment: Thanks, "cruft" is useful. In this particular case, however, it wasn't really *code* — just a single JSP file that was essentially empty (but whose *existence* still caused a [bug](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10997180/56285)) — so, a countable noun would be preferred. "Relic", suggested by others, is close to what I was looking for.